# Turning an inner join into a delete record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
use VIM_VCDB;

select VPX_ENTITY.NAME as "VM Name",  VPX_VM.FILE_NAME as "File Name / Path"
From VPX_VM inner join VPX_Entity 
on vpx_vm.ID = vpx_entity.ID
order by VPX_entity.name
```

I would like to use this record to delete the returned dataset from both tables simultaneously. Is this possible?

Comment: IMO, deleting from two tables with one `DELETE` statement is not possible without using any `TRIGGER` ;).

Comment: What sql server are you running it on? Look into cascading deletes. If not, you'll have to run two separate delete statements, once for each table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012. This is the VMware vcenter db, so I am cautious but have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM VPX_VM
       FROM VPX_Entity
Where vpx_vm.ID = vpx_entity.ID ...

Comment: Thanks I will try this, but would this not leave the record in the other table in tact? I guess I can delete that manually...

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` statement only deletes rows from one table.  However, you can wrap them in a transaction so they "take effect" at the same time:

```
begin transaction twodeletes;

    select vpx_vm.ID
    into #deleteids
    From VPX_VM inner join
         VPX_Entity 
         on vpx_vm.ID = vpx_entity.ID;

    delete from VPX_VM where id in (select id from #deleteids);
    delete from VPX_Entity where id in (select id from #deleteids);

commit transaction twodeletes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting simultaneously is not possible. Although you can use below workarounds:

1. Add a flag to the tables. Set it to Yes, so as to mark for deletion. 
   Then you can delete from the tables by filtering out del_flag='Y' records.

   update VPX_VM set del_flag='Y'
   where exists
   (select 1 from VPX_Entity
   vpx_vm.ID = vpx_entity.ID
   );

   update VPX_ENTITY set del_flag='Y'
   where exists
   (select 1 from VPX_VM
   vpx_vm.ID = vpx_entity.ID
   );

   Delete from VPX_VM where del_flag='Y';
   Delete from VPX_ENTITY where del_flag='Y';
2. Get the data returned from the query into another table tmp1 and then delete records from the two tables one by one by

   delete from VPX_VM where ID in (select vpx_vm_ID in tmp1);

   delete from VPX_Entity where ID in (select vpx_entity_id in tmp1);